# Fieldset disabled doesn't work on IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, fieldset, disabled-input

I am using angularjs with fieldset

```
<fieldset ng-disabled="true">
```

Currently, by some google search and trying some workaround for this issues but it still not work in disabled mode:
I still can edit input field while it's disabled

Anyone has the same problem and any idea for this ?
IE version: 11.0.14393.0
Thank you

Comment: Checkout [this reported bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/962368/can-still-edit-input-type-text-within-fieldset-disabled#). Also there are 2 workaround mentioned there, you can try them.

Comment: I have been tried it with my application but seems it doesn't help !

Answer (score 2):

Try this workarround:

```
fieldset[disabled] {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: This works, but I still have the issue that the checkboxes are not  grayed out :( How do you frustrate me, Edge and IE!